# Can I put a time limit on interstitial video length?

Tags: admob

Some interstitial ads uses video, can I exclude video interstitial or put a time limit on the length of the video or the time until the **X** appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable video ads from appearing in interstitial ads.

Go to the admob console, select **Apps->[your app name]->Ad units->[the interstitial ad]**

Now, click on **"Advance settings" -> "Ad type"** and disable video.

As for the video duration, I don't know if it can be limited.